# How do you use the AO node with a baked image texture?

Tags: ambient-occlusion

[image]I downloaded a texture off of poliigon.com and it has an AO image texture. I'm familiar with AO, but I don't know how to use the image texture. All I have is the image

Comment: maybe try to mix your AO and your second Image Texture into a MixRGB (Multiply mode), and plug this MixRGB into the Base Color input of the Principled BSDF?

Comment: [https://i.imgur.com/VqtDMce.png] Like this?@moonboots

Comment: yes, not sure about the Image Texture plugged into the AO though, what is it supposed to do? Also to get AO you generally need to plug it into a ColorRamp otherwise it will be too discrete, but again, I don't know a lot about your object etc